# How to apply css to bookmark link - effect?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I use a side menu within a product page, I'm navigating using bookmarks.  The problem is that the bookmark opens the section slightly out of the screen.  Combine this with a fixed menu at the top, and I'm losing a good 100px of content that a user then has to scroll back up with.  Is there some way to apply a class to adjust how the bookmark works?

Comment: Please provide relevant example code.

Comment: Yes please provide a link to where this is happening or a jsFiddle

Comment: It's more of just how a bookmark typically works.  For example, when you click a link that takes you to a bookmark, by default the bookmark heading is at the top of the page.  My question is if there is a way to have a bookmark open higher or lower than by default.  So if I wanted the bookmark to open lower down the page.